# Where to get Ubuntu 10.04 (not 10.04.1)?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I need the original released 10.04 server AMD64... This seems to be GONE from the Internet... Any ideas?

Comment: It's gone for a good reason:  1500 security and bug fixes that would get applied immediately after installing anyway.  Can I ask why you want the old version?  There might be another way to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm assuming you're an iso collector so you need specifically 10.04. :)

You could [search for torrent files outside ubuntu domains](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=ubuntu+10.04+64+torrent+-ubuntu.com). I can't post some torrent sites that have it because they contain some warez as well, but doing a little search for the first 3 pages, you're going to find a torrent with enough seeders.

Beware though that you should check the iso's checksum to avoid problems.